# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'connected_component_subgraphs'

Tags: python, error-handling, networkx

```
B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(data['movie'].unique(), bipartite=0, label='movie')
B.add_nodes_from(data['actor'].unique(), bipartite=1, label='actor')
B.add_edges_from(edges, label='acted')

A = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(B))[0]
```

I am getting the below given error when am trying to use `nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)`.

In the dataset there are two coumns(movie and actor), and it's in the form bipartite graph.

I want to get connected components for the movie nodes.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-efff4e6fafc4> in <module>
----> 1 A = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(B))[0]

AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'connected_component_subgraphs'
```

Comment: What version are you using? What do you get from `nx.__version__`

Comment: it is version 2.4.

Comment: Can't reproduce... I have 2.3 and can call `nx.connected_component_subgraphs` without problems

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This was deprecated with version 2.1, and finally removed with version 2.4.

See [these instructions](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.1/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_component_subgraphs.html)

> Use `(G.subgraph(c) for c in connected_components(G))`
>
> Or `(G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in connected_components(G))`

Comment: Solves the issue. Thank you joel.

Comment: networkx.exception.NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for directed type

Comment: @CSQGB - do you have a question?  If so, please start a new question.  I cannot determine what the issue is from the information you've given (some command isn't implemented for directed graph, but which command?)

Answer (score 9):

`connected_component_subgraphs`
has been removed from the networkx library.
You can use the alternative described in the deprecation notice.

For your example, refer to the code below:

```
A = (B.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(B))
A = list(A)[0]
```

Comment: subgraphs = (self.digraph.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.strongly_connected_components(self.digraph)) #<generator object

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code for single line alternative

```
A=list(B.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(B))[0]
```

Or you can install the previous version of networkx

```
pip install networkx==2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

First I got

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'iterable'.

To fix the above error, I upgraded networkx using

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall  network
```

It installed unetworkx-2.6.3, I got the error

> AttributeError: module networkx has no attribute
> connected_component_subgraphs.

I used the below code as mentioned by ABHISHEK D, it resolved. Thanks.

```
A=list(B.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(B))[0]
```