# Error for max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(),) no attribute 'connected_component_subgraphs'

Tags: python, networkx, tweepy

I am trying to run this code:

```
graph = nx.Graph()

largest_subgraph = max(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(graph), key=len)
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'connected_component_subgraphs'
```

How do I get around that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

connected_component_subgraphs() has been removed from version 2.4.

Instead, use this:

```
graph = nx.Graph()

connected_component_subgraphs = (graph.subgraph(c) for c in nx.connected_components(graph))

largest_subgraph = max(connected_component_subgraphs, key=len)
```

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61156053/1629102).

Comment: Ah ok I see. Set that as a variable. I also think it should be ```nx.connected_components(graph)``` Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, you don't have to set connected_component_subgraphs as a variable; I just did it for readability. The favorite habitat of bugs is in complex and tense code. And sorry for the mistake with the missing "nx."; I corrected that now. I did not test it as I didn't have the networkx library installed.

Comment: That's fine. I am just glad I was about to get some insight & help. Much appreciated. Yeah bugs love finding home in complex codes...