# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_scipy_sparse_matrix'

Tags: graph, deep-learning, neural-network, model, gnn

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-85-6e1936149908> in <cell line: 2>()
          1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    ----> 2 ax = draw_graph(A, ax=ax, size_factor=1)
    
    <ipython-input-83-384ee4aa675e> in draw_graph(A, m, ax, spring_layout, size_factor)
         26     assert m**2 == A.shape[0] == A.shape[1]
         27     # Create the nx.Graph object
    ---> 28     G = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(A)
         29     print('Number of nodes: %d; Number of edges: %d' % \
         30           (G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges()))
    
    AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_scipy_sparse_matrix'
```

Error is coming after:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    ax = draw_graph(A, ax=ax, size_factor=1)
```

Code to define graph:

```
   def grid_graph(m, k=8, corners=False):
    '''
    To create adjacency matrix as per Defferrard et al. 2016
    '''
    z = graph.grid(m)
    dist, idx = graph.distance_sklearn_metrics(z, k=k, metric='euclidean')
    A = graph.adjacency(dist, idx)

    # Connections are only vertical or horizontal on the grid.
    # Corner vertices are connected to 2 neightbors only.
    if corners:
        import scipy.sparse
        A = A.toarray()
        A[A < A.max()/1.5] = 0
        A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)
        print('{} edges'.format(A.nnz))

    print("{} > {} edges".format(A.nnz//2, k*m**2//2))
    return A


    def draw_graph(A, m=28, ax=None, spring_layout=False, size_factor=10):
        '''Draw the graph given adjacency matrix(A),
        optionally with spring_layout.
        '''
        assert m**2 == A.shape[0] == A.shape[1]
        # Create the nx.Graph object
        G = nx.from_scipy_sparse_matrix(A)
        print('Number of nodes: %d; Number of edges: %d' % \
              (G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges()))
        grid_coords = graph.grid(m)
    
        if spring_layout:
            # remove nodes without edges
            nodes_without_edges = [n for n, k in  G.degree() if k == 0]
            G.remove_nodes_from(nodes_without_edges)
            print('After removing nodes without edges:')
            print('Number of nodes: %d; Number of edges: %d' % \
                  (G.number_of_nodes(), G.number_of_edges()))
        
        z = graph.grid(m)
        
        # initial positions
        pos = {n: z[n] for n in G.nodes()} 
        
        if spring_layout:
            pos = nx.spring_layout(G, 
                                   pos=pos,
                                   iterations=200)
        
        ax = nx.draw(G, pos,
                     node_size=[G.degree(n) * size_factor for n in G.nodes()],
                     ax=ax
                    )
        return ax
```

Comment: duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154740/attributeerror-module-networkx-has-no-attribute-connected-component-subgraph

Comment: Any idea about scipy_sparse_matrix?

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of networkx to_scipy_sparse_matrix (which was an older command: see [the older documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix.html#networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix)) is replaced by to_scipy_sparse_array (see [the new documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_array.html)).

So use this instead:

```
G = nx.to_scipy_sparse_array(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

The from_scipy_sparse_matrix function was introduced in NetworkX version 2.6. If you're using an older version of NetworkX, you won't have access to this function. To resolve this issue, you can upgrade your NetworkX version to 2.6

```
pip uninstall networkx -y
pip install networkx==2.6.0
```

Or if you prefer the new version of Networkx like 3.2.1, you can switch from `from_scipy_sparse_matrix` to `from_scipy_sparse_array`