# Why is it showing an error with module networkx has no attribute?

Tags: python, networkx, social-networking

I am trying to plot a graph using networkx
`your text`

```
plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))
user_net = bi.weighted_projected_graph(fb_g, users, ratio=False)
user_net = max(net.connected_component_subgraphs(user_net),key=len)
weights = [math.log(edata['weight'])for f,t,edata in user_net.edges(data=True)]

net.draw_spring(topic_net, label = 'user_net', node_color='g', with_labels=True, node_size =300, font_color ='w')
plt.legend(["user_net"])
plt.show()
```

error:

```
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'connected_component_subgraphs'
<Figure size 1100x1100 with 0 Axes>
```

I expected to see a plot

Comment: Is this relevant; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61154740/attributeerror-module-networkx-has-no-attribute-connected-component-subgraph ?